# How to generate all character trigrams from a file?

Tags: text-processing, command-line

How do I generate all character-level trigrams from a file using standard unix tools like `awk`, `sed`, `tr`, etc.?

Example file content:

```
BIKE CAR HOUSE HELLO DO HELP
```

Should yield these trigrams:

```
BIK
IKE
CAR
HOU
OUS
USE
HEL
ELL
LLO
DO
HEL
ELP
```

Comment: Is this homework? In your own interest you should make a good-faith attempt at solving it yourself first. Should you then come across specific issues with your approach then feel free to ask here.